# Is there a function in python that gives you the boolean intersection of two 2d matrices?

Tags: python-3.x, matrix

I am trying to take two binary 3d matrices and find their boolean intersection. An example of a matrices that I trying to use can be found in the pictures I attached from excel. I figured this would be the easiest way for ya'll to understand without me putting a ton of code in this question.  Both of these matrices will be projected so that they are the same size.

```
matrix1 = [[[1,0,1],[1,0,1],[1,1,1]],[[1,0,1],[1,0,1],[1,1,1]],[[1,0,1],[1,0,1],[1,1,1]]]

matrix2 = [[[1,0,1],[1,0,1],[1,1,1]],[[1,0,1],[1,0,1],[1,1,1]],[[1,0,1],[1,0,1],[1,1,1]]]

matrix3 = ##I need their boolean intersection
```

These two 2d matrices will be projected into 3d, making them square from an overhead view

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour]. What's your expected output? Please [edit] to add. Also are you aware of `numpy`? This seems like something it could do.

Answer (score 0):

The Boolean intersection is just the AND operator on each pair of elements, so you can use a list comprehension in a recursive function like so:

```
def Intersect(a, b):
    if type(a) == list and type(b) == list:
        return [Intersect(x, y) for x, y in zip(a, b)]
    return a and b
```

This doesn't check if the matrices are actually the same shape, you can do that separately first or check inside the recursive function.